# iOS8 and slick carousel swipe issue in standalone app

Tags: web-applications, mobile-safari, carousel, swipe, iphone-standalone-web-app

The webApp with slick carousel is added to Home Screen using Safari browser n IOS8 using 'Add to Home Screen' option from the screen where the carousel is present. Then after opening the standalone app from the Home screen, then the carousel swipe is not working (the auto slide too). If we refresh the page then it starts working. Tried with iOS7, Android Chrome, then it is working.
Could any one please help me in this?